# Using the diff command to compare two strings?

Tags: linux, string, diff

According to https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm

> The `diff` command analyzes two files and prints the lines that are
> different.

Can I use the same `diff` command to compare two strings?

```
$ more file*
::::::::::::::
file1.txt
::::::::::::::
hey
::::::::::::::
file2.txt
::::::::::::::
hi
```

```
$ diff file1.txt file2.txt 
1c1
< hey
---
> hi
```

Instead of saving the content of `hey` and `hi` into two different files, can I read it directly?

By the way, there are no files named `hey` or `hi` in the example below, which is why I get `No such file or directory` error messages.

```
$ diff hey hi
diff: hey: No such file or directory
diff: hi: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can use `diff` on two strings, if you make files from them, because `diff`  will only ever compare files.

A shortcut way to do that is using process substitutions in a shell that supports these:

```bash
diff <( printf '%s\n' "$string1" ) <( printf '%s\n' "$string2" )
```

Example:

```
$ diff <( printf '%s\n' "hey" ) <( printf '%s\n' "hi" )
1c1
< hey
---
> hi
```

In other shells,

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$string1" >tmpfile
printf '%s\n' "$string2" | diff tmpfile -
rm -f tmpfile
```

In this second example, one file contains the first string, while the second string is given to `diff` on standard input.  `diff` is invoked with the file containing the first string as its first argument.  As its second argument, `-` signals that it should read standard input (on which the second string will arrive via `printf`).

Comment: See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Answer (score 0):

For folks wishing to use strings instead of files input for the 'diff' command in Script Editor (AppleScript), I found the following worked after some toil:

```
do shell script "bash -c 'diff -y <(echo '\\''" & string1 & "'\\'') <(echo '\\''" & string2 & "'\\'')'
```

Note the need to present the code as a string to be run within the bash shell and the wicked escape tokens.