# Show differences in strings

Tags: git, diff

This answer shows how to `diff` two strings - [Using the diff command to compare two strings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582796/using-the-diff-command-to-compare-two-strings?answertab=active#tab-top)

I try:

```
diff <( printf '%s\n' "tring1" ) <( printf '%s\n' "string2" )
```

The output is:

```
1c1
< tring1
---
> string2
```

This shows that the two strings are different.

I would like to know at which characters the two strings are different, or at least the first character where the difference starts. How can I do it?

This is important when comparing long urls.

I study other answers based on `git diff` at [diff within a line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/diff-within-a-line)

I try

`git diff --word-diff --word-diff-regex=. <( printf '%s\n' "tring1" ) <( printf '%s\n' "string2" )`

The output is:

```
diff --git a/dev/fd/63 b/dev/fd/62
index 9234a649..b6ce327a 120000
--- a/dev/fd/63
+++ b/dev/fd/62
@@ -1 +1 @@
pipe:[69160538[-6-]{+8+}]
```

I am not sure if I apply `git diff` correctly and how to interpret the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [diff within a line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/diff-within-a-line)

Comment: @StephenKitt if `git diff` has this functionality then it is better to provide a straitghtforward solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the kind of output you are expecting. Does this need to be something like "the two strings differ at positions 1 and 7"?

Comment: @terdon counting positions could be complicated in long strings. A more appropriate output is showing insertions and deletions in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific use-case, store the strings in files, and compare those with `git diff`:

```
$ echo tring1 > f1
$ echo string2 > f2
$ git diff --word-diff --word-diff-regex=. --no-index f1 f2
diff --git a/f1 b/f2
index e8ae123..d704b3b 100644
--- a/f1
+++ b/f2
@@ -1 +1 @@
{+s+}tring[-1-]{+2+}
```

This shows that the “s” character was added at the start of the string, and that “1” became “2”.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmp -b <( printf '%s\n' "tring1" ) <( printf '%s\n' "string2" )
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 differ: byte 1, line 1 is 164 t 163 s
```

`cmp` - *compare two files byte by byte*